# Primary key and Data Type for an Audit Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am about to create an auditing table, which basically records 3 events (for now). Creation of a user, a user login event (Success) and a user login event which failed.

My idea is a very simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE AccountAuditLog (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    IPAddress VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    EventType VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    EventDescription VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    EventTimestamp DATETIME2 NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_AccountAuditLog PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_AccountAuditLog_Account FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Account (Id)
)
```

We usually use UNIQUEIDENTIFIERs as Ids, but my reasoning for the Id INT is that it simply auto increments which provides some information (Yes, we can use DateTime to work out the order, but the rows will be written in an order?).

Is there any problem with using an IDENTITY column on an audit log? I can't think of one.

Then, a requirement to show the login count for a user. I'd prefer not to have a field called LoginCount on the Account table. Instead, I'd like to just do a COUNT() where UserId = Id. If I had an index on UserId - I believe this would be very efficient even with large volumes of data. Is that s illy plan, or more suited than a field on the Account table that get's incremented each login?

Comment: Is there any reason you should create a primary key on the audit table? I can't think of one. This table isn't really a relational table, it's lust a log, so I suggest you just create useful indexes to support the anticipated queries.

Comment: Easy read: [Why GUIDs are not a good idea for SQL Server Primary Keys](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1504/why-guids-are-not-a-good-idea-for-sql-server-primary-keys.aspx). The take-away: `A good clustering key should be sequential. But, a GUID that is not sequential [...] can be a bad choice`.

Comment: Thanks Dan. It was more for uniqueness. Or else the OK could maybe be across the UserId and the EventTimestamp? That would assist with the '... WHERE UserId = x' queries?

Comment: Thanks TT. The pattern of the place i now work is UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS as the PKs. I can't change that, but I'm trying to make sure this table is as efficient as possible, and I feel it's a great candidate for an INT PK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you will create the Primary key over the table then it will be better way to manage shorting over the data.
For the login count, you should use below query,

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM AccountAuditLog
WHERE UserId  = ? and EventType = ?
```

But, make sure you should have an index over columns, which are in where clause.